# Expressing Logarithims in terms of variables

Tags: logarithms

I need help answering this for my HW. I've tried to answer it myself but I just couldn't do it. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out :)

[image: Click to See Picture of Question]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the rules of log's on your first two expressions, you'll get two equations in the variables $\log x$ and $\log y,$ which you can solve.  E.g., the first expression becomes $\log x + 3 \log y = m$.  Once you know $\log x$ and $\log y$, apply the log rules to the last expression and plug in.

Comment: I see whatt you mean but idk how that will remove both logx and logy and result in an expression with only m and n as variables. Can u show me your solution? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: If you replace $\log x$ by $A$ and $\log y$ by $B$, you have a linear system in two unknowns.  Solve for $A$ and $B$ in the usual way.